# How to preserve Socket.io sockets app-wide

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I am trying to add socket.io functionality to my App.

I have never used socket.io before, so I have no idea how to progress from here.

I've used the MERN Stack until now, and the next step would be to implement socket.io for chat functionality. The problem is, I don't know when to connect, and how to preserve my sockets. The user can sign in, so I thought I could just connect after signing the user in, but then the socket is created in a component, and I can't access it from anywhere else.

The problem is, I use JWT tokens for authentication, so I have a function, that "signs the user in" when going to a new page, if the token hasn't expired yet.

```js
if(localStorage.jwtToken){
    const token = localStorage.jwtToken;
    setAuthToken(token);
    const user = jwt_decode(token);
    store.dispatch(action_setCurrentUser(user));
    store.dispatch(setGroupsOfUser({ id: user.id }));
    const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000;
    if(user.exp < currentTime){
        store.dispatch(logoutUser());
        window.location.href = './login';
    }
}
```

I thought I could just connect in here, but then my ChatView component can't access it to send messages and stuff. I need a socket to send notifications, even if the user isn't in a chat room, and the ChatView component needs it to send messages.

Tried to connect after the login dispatch, and store the online users on the server, with their socketIDs.

If I try to search for a solution, every hit I get is about authentication using socket.io, but the authentication is already done for me so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Have you tried setting up the sockets at the top - app level?

Comment: Not above App.js, how do I assign a user to the socket then? Do you mean in index.js?

Comment: Sorry I meant at app,js level? Your problem seems to be just setting it up at a sub component right?

Comment: Yeah, I mean, I need it in my subcomponents. Do you think it would work if I connect in app.js and pass the socket down to the subcomponents with the Route?

Comment: Yeah absolutely - you should setup your sockets at the root (app) level, with dispatchers - your sub components can subscribe to that then and upon any changes they'll receive the update...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, I decided to create the socket in my App.js and store it in my state.
I can use this stored state then in my subcomponents, and assign it on the server to a user after sign in.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look in redux. Since your having all the auth stuff and all . It might get messy handling app wide authentication .